# Java Thread Dump java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking) Interpretation

Tags: java

I did a thread dump on my application which was having a consistent CPU spike over 100% and I have 30 threads in the **java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)** state.  Below is an example of one from the dump.  Anyone know how to interpret these?

```
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (14.0-b16 mixed mode):

"hz.1.threads._hzInstance_1_spot-gen2-prod.cached.thread-31" prio=10 tid=0x00007f143003a800 nid=0x1b07 waiting on condition [0x00007f146c341000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00007f14932fd3a0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

"ajp-8009-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f036a000 nid=0x1b04 runnable [0x00007f146c442000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.accept(Native Method)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Acceptor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1156)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

"ajp-8009-CometPoller-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f0ca3000 nid=0x1b03 in Object.wait() [0x00007f146c543000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller.run(AprEndpoint.java:1313)
        - locked <0x00007f148e6ab818> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

"ajp-8009-Poller-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f05b3000 nid=0x1b02 in Object.wait() [0x00007f146c644000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller.run(AprEndpoint.java:1313)
        - locked <0x00007f148e67b438> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

"http-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f0953000 nid=0x1b01 runnable [0x00007f146c745000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.accept(Native Method)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Acceptor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1156)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

"http-8080-Sendfile-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f05b0000 nid=0x1b00 in Object.wait() [0x00007f146d460000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Sendfile.run(AprEndpoint.java:1771)
        - locked <0x00007f148e5c7ac8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Sendfile)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

"http-8080-CometPoller-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f0c03800 nid=0x1aff in Object.wait() [0x00007f146d35f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller.run(AprEndpoint.java:1313)
        - locked <0x00007f148e5c7700> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

"http-8080-Poller-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f099e800 nid=0x1afe in Object.wait() [0x00007f146d25e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller.run(AprEndpoint.java:1313)
        - locked <0x00007f148e5a39e8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

"ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f0a01000 nid=0x1afd waiting on condition [0x00007f146d561000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1579)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

        hz.2.threads._hzInstance_2_dev.cached.thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00007f14651bc000 nid=0x1afc waiting on condition [0x00007f146c846000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f149609a970> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "Mojarra-ResourceCache-1-thread-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f068f000 nid=0x1afb waiting on condition [0x00007f146d965000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f1491c8b7b0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
            at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:193)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:688)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:681)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.1.threads._hzInstance_1_spot-gen2-prod.cached.thread-30" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1430039000 nid=0x1af5 waiting on condition [0x00007f146d662000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f14932fd3a0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.TCP.Listener" prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f088c800 nid=0x1af4 runnable [0x00007f146d763000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:375)
            at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:470)
            at com.hazelcast.impl.management.ManagementCenterService$SocketReadyServerSocket.doAccept(ManagementCenterService.java:585)
            at com.hazelcast.impl.management.ManagementCenterService$TCPListener.run(ManagementCenterService.java:173)

    "hz.UDP.Sender" prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f0d13000 nid=0x1af3 waiting on condition [0x00007f146d864000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
            at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
            at com.hazelcast.impl.management.ManagementCenterService$UDPSender.run(ManagementCenterService.java:228)

    "hz.UDP.Listener" prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f04fd000 nid=0x1af2 runnable [0x00007f146de6a000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
            at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
            - locked <0x00007f1495f28108> (a java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:135)
            - locked <0x00007f1495f28108> (a java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl)
            at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:729)
            - locked <0x00007f1496029668> (a java.net.DatagramPacket)
            - locked <0x00007f1496015fb0> (a java.net.DatagramSocket)
            at com.hazelcast.impl.management.ManagementCenterService$UDPListener.run(ManagementCenterService.java:197)

    "hz.2.MulticastThread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f080f800 nid=0x1af0 runnable [0x00007f146da66000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
            at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
            at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
            at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
            at com.hazelcast.config.GroupConfig.readData(GroupConfig.java:118)
            at com.hazelcast.config.Config.readData(Config.java:641)
            at com.hazelcast.cluster.JoinRequest.readData(JoinRequest.java:68)
            at com.hazelcast.cluster.JoinInfo.readData(JoinInfo.java:59)
            at com.hazelcast.impl.MulticastService.receive(MulticastService.java:128)
            - locked <0x00007f1496026d98> (a java.lang.Object)
            at com.hazelcast.impl.MulticastService.run(MulticastService.java:101)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.2.ServiceThread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f0a0f800 nid=0x1aef in Object.wait() [0x00007f146db67000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
            at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
            at com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterService.run(ClusterService.java:168)
            - locked <0x00007f1496026db0> (a java.lang.Object)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.2.OutThread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f068b800 nid=0x1aee runnable [0x00007f146dc68000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:230)
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:83)
            at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
            - locked <0x00007f1496026dc8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$1)
           - locked <0x00007f1496026de0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
            - locked <0x00007f14952a5b98> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
            at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
            at com.hazelcast.nio.SelectorBase.run(SelectorBase.java:124)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.2.InThread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f14f0a99000 nid=0x1aed runnable [0x00007f146dd69000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:230)
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:83)
            at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
            - locked <0x00007f1496026df8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$1)
            - locked <0x00007f1496026e10> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
            - locked <0x00007f14952a5c10> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
            at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
            at com.hazelcast.nio.SelectorBase.run(SelectorBase.java:124)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.1.threads._hzInstance_1_spot-gen2-prod.cached.thread-29" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1430037000 nid=0x1aea waiting on condition [0x00007f146df6b000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f14932fd3a0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.1.threads._hzInstance_1_spot-gen2-prod.cached.thread-28" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1430035000 nid=0x1ae9 waiting on condition [0x00007f146e06c000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f14932fd3a0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
           at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.1.threads._hzInstance_1_spot-gen2-prod.cached.thread-27" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1430033000 nid=0x1ae8 waiting on condition [0x00007f146e16d000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f14932fd3a0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.1.threads._hzInstance_1_spot-gen2-prod.cached.thread-26" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1430031000 nid=0x1ae7 waiting on condition [0x00007f148818d000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f14932fd3a0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.1.threads._hzInstance_1_spot-gen2-prod.cached.thread-25" prio=10 tid=0x00007f143002f000 nid=0x1ae6 waiting on condition [0x00007f148828e000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f14932fd3a0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.1.threads._hzInstance_1_spot-gen2-prod.cached.thread-24" prio=10 tid=0x00007f143002d000 nid=0x1ae5 waiting on condition [0x00007f148838f000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f14932fd3a0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.1.threads._hzInstance_1_spot-gen2-prod.cached.thread-23" prio=10 tid=0x00007f143002b000 nid=0x1ae4 waiting on condition [0x00007f1488490000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f14932fd3a0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.1.threads._hzInstance_1_spot-gen2-prod.cached.thread-22" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1430029000 nid=0x1ae3 waiting on condition [0x00007f1488591000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f14932fd3a0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.1.threads._hzInstance_1_spot-gen2-prod.cached.thread-21" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1430027000 nid=0x1ae2 waiting on condition [0x00007f1488692000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f14932fd3a0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.1.threads._hzInstance_1_spot-gen2-prod.cached.thread-20" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1430025000 nid=0x1ae1 waiting on condition [0x00007f1488793000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f14932fd3a0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.1.threads._hzInstance_1_spot-gen2-prod.cached.thread-19" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1430023000 nid=0x1ae0 waiting on condition [0x00007f1488894000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f14932fd3a0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.1.threads._hzInstance_1_spot-gen2-prod.cached.thread-18" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1430021000 nid=0x1adf waiting on condition [0x00007f1488995000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f14932fd3a0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

    "hz.1.threads._hzInstance_1_spot-gen2-prod.cached.thread-17" prio=10 tid=0x00007f143001f000 nid=0x1ade waiting on condition [0x00007f1488a96000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x00007f14932fd3a0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:453)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Comment: Normally the thead is in in this state when it is waiting on the wait() method. This should not consume the processor. Are you sure all of your threads are in the TIMED_WAITING state?

Comment: I added more of the stack, but yest it seems all are in the TIMED_WAITING state

Comment: did you verify that the cpu spike is from this process?

Comment: @MiserableVariable - I don't have a profiler so I'm not sure how to accomplish that...but I'm pretty confident

Comment: Which OS? On windows, you can just keep an eye on the taskmanager (sorted by cpu usage) or use the built in performance monitors. Don't add to the already loaded CPU with profiler.